# How to clear or dispose current page in Crystal Report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Currently I can generate a report in CrystalReportViewer1 via Button1.
How can I delete the current contents of the report. I need to print another record on it.

im using VB.net

```
Dim rep As WorkFileTags1 = New WorkFileTags1()
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
    rep.Refresh()
    Connect()
    reader = New SqlCommand("select     c_sfr,c_pn,c_sn,c_po,c_dateReceived,c_received from tbl_workfile where c_sfr = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", conn).ExecuteReader
    DT.Load(reader)
    rep.SetDataSource(DT)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
```

Comment: @feltersnach posted sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `ReportSource` to `Nothing` and then use `Refresh()` to reload the ReportViewer.

```
Dim rep As WorkFileTags1 = New WorkFileTags1()
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
rep.Refresh()
Connect()
reader = New SqlCommand("select     c_sfr,c_pn,c_sn,c_po,c_dateReceived,c_received from tbl_workfile where c_sfr = '" & ComboBox1.Text & "' ", conn).ExecuteReader
DT.Load(reader)
rep.SetDataSource(DT)
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rep
```

You can add a button to clear it and add the following to the button's event

`CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Nothing
 CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()`

Comment: Tried it. it refreshes the view but nothing happens still prints on the bottom of the previous report.

Comment: Ah, Yeah there appears to be some code missing so I did not see that. Glad it worked! If my answer helped you out, please be sure to accept it :)